# What does *args mean?

Tags: ruby

What does `args` mean, and what is different between it and `ARGV` if there is a difference?

```
 def puts_two(*args)
    arg1, arg2 = args
    puts "arg1: #{arg1}, arg2: #{arg2}"
    end
```

Answer (score 6):

In this case, *args and ARGV have nothing to do with each other. In your example:

```
def puts_two(*args)
    arg1, arg2 = args
    puts "arg1: #{arg1}, arg2: #{arg2}"
end
```

*args is just the parameters passed to the method puts_two. The * is the 'splat' operator, which means any number of arguments can be passed to the method and they will be 'splatted' in to an array. So if you called it with:

puts_two('one', 'two', 'three')

args will be an array that looks like ['one', 'two', 'three'].

Notice that in the assignment of the variables arg1 and arg2 only the first 2 elements of the array will be used, so using my example above

```
arg1, arg2 = ['one', 'two', 'three']

arg1 => 'one'
arg2 => 'two'
```

ARGV is simply the arguments passed to the ruby script from the command line.

Answer (score 4):

This is referred to as the "splat operator" in Ruby. See the following article for different uses:

[The Strange Ruby Splat](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/)

In a method definition it basically just gathers all remaining arguments into a single array (note that since Ruby 2.0 there's also the possibility to gather keyword args with something like `**kwargs`).

Answer (score 3):

`*` is called *splat operator*.In `*args` here `*` creating an array with all the arguments sent to the method `puts_two`, and `args` as a local variable holds the reference to the array. In more clear way - *The splat operator is used to handle methods which have a variable parameter list(ie Arraying your arguments).*

[`ARGV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-argv) *contains the arguments passed to your script, one per element.*

**For example:**

```
$ ruby argf.rb -v glark.txt
```

In `argf.rb` file, you will get as below :

```
ARGF.argv   #=> ["-v", "glark.txt"]
```

Answer (score 3):

ARGV is a special variable in Ruby. It contains the arguments passed to the script on the command line. For example, if you write the following code in a file called test.rb:

```
ARGV.each do |a|
    puts a
end
```

and call it like this

```
c:\> ruby test.rb one two
```

will display

```
one
two
```

In the code you posted, `*args` simply indicates that the method accepts a variable number of arguments in an array called `args`. It could have been called anything you want (following the Ruby naming rules, of course).

So in this case, `args` is totally unrelated to `ARGV`.